# unique index with doctrine mongodb odm

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

i'm doing a registration system for my site and want to prevent duplicate registrations with the same email address.

the declaration of the user class looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Document
 */
class User extends BaseEntity
{
    private 
    /**
     * @Id
     */
    $id,

    /**
     * @String @Index(unique=true)
     */    
    $email
;
}
```

but whenever i save a user with the same email, no exception is raised and i get a duplicate.

i found somewhere that i need to do $documentManager->flush(array('safe'=>true)); but that doesn't help.

How can I achieve what i need? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  The index is not being created by Doctrine as you can see by typing the following in the mongo console:

```
db.system.indexes.find()
```

I had to create my index directly in mongo per [these instructions.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) After that duplicates won't be created.

However Symfony2/Doctrine doesn't seem to throw any exceptions, the insert just fails silently. Mongodb DOES alert you of the failed insert if you do it directly in the console.

--edit: An exception **is** thrown when `array('safe'=>true)` is used as a parameter to flush() as per the original post.

Comment: actually, i found that you need to call $schemaTool->ensureIndexes(); when creating the database. after that it works as expected

Comment: I had a similare problem that my index was ignored make sure you migrate with the right doctrine task for example:  
  
Use:  
`php app/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update`

Answer (score 0):

I am new to MongoDB and was having similar problem while configuring the doctrine mongo db in my project.

I used PHPStorm's DB tools to check if indexes are created. As you can see in the image there is no index shown for `UserDevice` collection
[image]

But I could see indexes when I run

```
db.getCollection("UserDevice").getIndexes()
```

[image]